# Cannot call 'fill' with argument

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, pine-script-v5

I can`t fill between ema and cmf! Thank you for your help!
////@version=5
//indicator(title="Chaikin Money Flow", shorttitle="CMF", format=format.price, precision=2,
//timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
//var cumVol = 0.
//cumVol += nz(volume)
//if barstate.islast and cumVol == 0
//    runtime.error("No volume is provided by the data vendor.")
//length = input.int(14, minval=1)
//ad = close==high and close==low or high==low ? 0 : ((2*close-low-high)/(high-low))*volume
//mf = math.sum(ad, length) / math.sum(volume, length)
//plot(mf, color=#43A047, title="MF")
//hline(0, color=#787B86, title="Zero", linestyle=hline.style_dashed)
//emaf = ta.ema(mf, 14)
//plot(emaf)
//fill(mf, emaf)

Comment: Please format your code as code blocks so that it is readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fill()` function receives plot objects specifically. So if you plot x and y and you want a fill between these plots, here's how it would work:

```
x = ta.sma(close, 10)
y = ta.sma(close, 20)
plot_x = plot(x)
plot_y = plot(y)
fill(x, y) // INCORRECT
fill(plot_x, plot_y) // CORRECT
```